# Why do I can't get the title by using POST method?

Tags: php, html, url, post, get

So I am trying to get the title from the URL by using $_GET['title'] in the first PHP file, but I can't get the file on the 2nd file.

URL:

[https://easy2book.000webhostapp.com/neworder.php?bookid=101&title=SENIOR%20secondary%20geography%20fieldwork%20and%20assessment%20practice%202021.%20For%20HKDSE%202021%20/%20Ip%20Kim%20Wai%20...%20[et%20al.]](https://easy2book.000webhostapp.com/neworder.php?bookid=101&title=SENIOR%20secondary%20geography%20fieldwork%20and%20assessment%20practice%202021.%20For%20HKDSE%202021%20/%20Ip%20Kim%20Wai%20...%20%5Bet%20al.%5D).

1st File:

```
<?php
  include_once 'header.php';
    $id2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['bookid']);
    $title2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['title']);
?>

<section class="neworder-form">
  <h2>Order</h2>
  <div class="neworder-form-form">
    <form action="neworder.inc.php" method="post">
      <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Book ID:</td>
              <td>
                 <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="bookid2" value="<?= $id2 ?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Book Title: </td>
              <td>
                 <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="title2" value="<?= $title2 ?>">
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>Username: </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="uid2" placeholder="Username...">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Comfirmed Book ID: </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="id2" placeholder="Please enter the Book ID....">
               </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      <button type="submit" name="submit2">Order</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php
    // Error messages
    if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
      if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyinput2") {
        echo "<p>Fill in all fields!</p>";
      }
      else if ($_GET["error"] == "usernametaken2") {
        echo "<p>Username already taken!</p>";
      }
    }
  ?>
</section>
```

2nd File:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit2"])) {

  // First we get the form data from the URL
  $uid2 = $_POST["uid2"];
  $id2 = $_POST["id2"];
  $title2 = $_POST["title2"];

  // Then we run a bunch of error handlers to catch any user mistakes we can (you can add more than I did)
  // These functions can be found in functions.inc.php

  require_once "dbh.inc.php";
  require_once 'functions2.inc.php';

  // Left inputs empty
  // We set the functions "!== false" since "=== true" has a risk of giving us the wrong outcome
  if (emptyInputOrder2($uid2,$id2) !== false) {
    header("location: ../neworder.php?error=emptyinput&bookid=$id2&title=$title2");
        exit();
  }
    
  // Is the username exists
  if (uidExists2($conn, $uid2) !== true) {
    header("location: ../neworder.php?error=undefineuser");
        exit();
  }

  // If we get to here, it means there are no user errors

  // Now we insert the user into the database
    createUser($conn, $uid2, $id2);

} else {
    header("location: ../neworder.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: `$title2 = $_POST[""];`? Forgot to write the index?

Comment: @El_Vanja replaced but still undefined

Comment: Doesn't make sense. `var_dump($_POST)` and see what it contains.

Comment: @El_Vanja [uid2] => [id2] => [submit2] It skipped the bookid2 and title2, maybe because I used value="<?= $title2 ?>" ?

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I'm so blind... they're disabled. Instead of using disabled inputs, you could just print the values directly on the page and use hidden inputs to transfer the value further.

Comment: Or use `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

Comment: I don't see you trying to access `bookid2` anywhere in the code. I only see `$id2 = $_POST["id2"];`.

Comment: @El_Vanja Solved

Answer (score -1):

- The input fields are disbled, disabled inputs are not posted.
- Replace $title2 = $_POST[""]; with $title2 = $_POST["title2"];

Comment: OP *is* posting the values. The first script takes the value from `$_GET` and places it inside the `value` of a text input.

Comment: My mistake, he should fill: $title2 = $_POST[""]; with $title2 = $_POST["title2"]; and check if value is set

Comment: @Firewizz tried to replace $title2 = $_POST[""]; with $title2 = $_POST["title2"]; still Undefined index: title2 in /storage/ssd1/923/16775923/public_html/neworder.inc.php on line 8

Comment: @WarrenChan Try to make the field readonly and not disabled. Disabled fields are not posted. (As El_Vanja mentioned ;) )